# Why nodes in multinode demo spent so much disk space

Tags: node

Basically question is on the title. I'm running 2 nodes and even without transaction history flag usage of disk space is concerning me. Since it using almost 1.5Gb for one hour of work without any load. Is it normal or I doing something wrong?